# Filtering an MS Access form using code upon opening

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to put a filter on a form "frmProjectCharter01" where upon opening it (from clicking a button) it will only show records where the field "OnLoad" in its underlying table "tblProjectMasterList" has a "non-null" value.

My current code is

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProjectCharter01"

Me.Filter = [OnLoad] Is Not Null
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a "compliation error" message where the private sub opening line is highlighted as well as the "[OnLoad]" field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Filter` property is a string expression, so you can avoid that compile error by adding quotes.

```vb
Me.Filter = "[OnLoad] Is Not Null"
```

However, from the rest of your question, my impression is you should do this with `OpenForm` *WhereCondition* (see the help topic for details) instead of setting a `Filter`:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProjectCharter01", WhereCondition:="[OnLoad] Is Not Null"
```

Comment: Thanks alot.  That definately worked.  One thing however that I just learned.  On the form to be opened, there is also a combobox where i would like the option to change the record. What I just learned is that the filter just created, installs the filter on the "on load" event so therefore once you are in the form (under the filter "onload is not null", you no longer have the option to change the record.  So what I am thinking is that i need to somehow write the code so that the combo box updates the field that is being refered to in the filter.. ??

Comment: You can use your combo box's After Update event to update the form's `Recordsource` to whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks Hans. That is kind of what I had in mind.  If you have a chance...   Would you mind explaining this code below which i use as an after event update:

Comment: DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "[ID Project] = " & Str(Nz(Screen.ActiveControl, 0))

Comment: I understand what it is doing, but i dont understand "acFirst" nor the Str(Nz...)  are these Access/VBA functions??

Comment: In the VB Editor, place your cursor on *SearchForRecord*, then press the F1 key.  Read about the "Record" parameter and notice that *acFirst* is a member of the *AcRecord* enum.  You can also find information about `Str()` and `Nz()` in the help system.

Comment: Grande Hans. Thanks mate"!

Comment: Hans last question, if it is not too laborious to explain.  When i use a combobox to update a record, my methodology involves using an object (usually the ID number of the record) which i hide on the form. Upon update, i take that object and use DAO code to write it somewhere else.. OUt of curiosity, is this the standard way of using a combo box to update records behind the scenes or is it possible there is a much easier and efficient way which I havent come accross yet...??